# How to get clientId with custom dimensions in google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-filters

I replace my current default "***universal google analytics***" code to custom JavaScript to get the clientId but I got string value while using (*Like: clientId*).

**GA code:**

> ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-x', 'auto'); ga(function(tracker){ var
>   clientId = tracker.get('clientId'); }); ga('set', 'dimension1',
>   clientId); ga('send', 'pageview');

Comment: dimensions are strings.  what did you expect exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would hardly work since you're assigning cilentID value to the function scoped variable that can not be seen outside the readyCallback function. 
Consider the following code:

```
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX', 'auto');
  ga(function(tracker) {
    var cid = tracker.get('clientId');
    tracker.set('dimension1', cid); // ID is to be set right after the traker is available
  });
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: How to generate userId likewise clientId. Is there any possible option?

Comment: userId feature is suggested to be provided from your back end. I suppost the best way to pass it to readyCallback is a global JS variable
  var uid = 'someId87687';
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX', 'auto');
  ga(function(tracker) {
    var cid = tracker.get('clientId');
    tracker.set('dimension1', cid); // ID is to be set right after the traker is available
  tracker.det('userId', uid);
  });
  ga('send', 'pageview');

Comment: I would like to create unique user id for each user and I'm new to JS is there  any possible ways to create unique user id? @Дмитро Булах

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: clientId is available through the API as ga:clientId

No need to set clientId (or userId) in a custom dimension anymore.

Note to anyone using the Universal Analytics User ID feature
The values returned in ga:clientId is actually the userId
Even more interessting. (As of time of writing) GA fails if you request clientId from a User ID view. So you should use a non-User ID view to get the User ID. :)